# Adicionar uma figura bmp ou jpg em um canvas no Delphi

Tags: delphi, canvas

É possível eu inserir, via programação, uma imagem jpg ou bmp em um canvas?

Estou usando o canvas em um TBitmap em tempo de programação, pois minha aplicação não possui tela. Ela é chamada, cria o desenho conforme parâmetros passados e sai.

Segue abaixo uma parte do meu código:

```
var
  bCan: TBitmap;
begin
  bCan := TBitmap.Create;
  bCan.Width := 800;
  bCan.Height := 500;
  bCan.Canvas.Lock;

  // Desenhos diversos com linhas e retângulos

  bCan.Canvas.Unlock;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelos comentários da outra resposta, você quer inserir um bitmap em uma posição específica de um canvas. A dúvida não é como carregar o bitmap, correto? Se for isso, basta utilizar este comando:

```
Canvas.Draw(x, y, bitmap);
```

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta. Seria melhor se você explicasse a solução que você encontrou.

Comment: @AsuraKhan ah, você foi mais rápido que eu.

Comment: @AckLay É o café. Tá fazendo efeito.

Comment: @AsuraKhan já estava escrito, só faltava clicar no enviar, quando apareceu... "novo comentário"... hehe

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo aqui. No meu caso era um TPicture, então eu usei img.bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Depende onde está a imagem que voce quer inserir no `bCan`.

Digamos que ela esteja em um diretório, você pode usar o comando `bCan.LoadFromFile`

Dá uma olhada nas variações do comando `LoadFrom...` do `TBitmap`

**Edit:**

Dá uma olhada, e vê se isso aqui serve para você:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    btnPosicionarImagem: TButton;
    btnCarregarImagem: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnPosicionarImagemClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCarregarImagemClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Image: TBitmap;
    Canvas: TControlCanvas;

    procedure CarregarImagemBitmap;
    procedure PosicionarPainel;
    procedure CarregarImagemCanvas;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}




procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image  := TBitmap.Create;
  Canvas := TControlCanvas.Create;
end;



procedure TForm2.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(Canvas);
  FreeAndNil(Image);
end;



procedure TForm2.CarregarImagemBitmap;
begin
  Image.LoadFromFile('C:\executaveis_01_256x256.bmp');
end;



procedure TForm2.PosicionarPainel;
begin
  Panel1.Width  := Image.Width;
  Panel1.Height := Image.Height;

  Panel1.Left := Random(100);
  Panel1.Top  := Random(100);
end;



procedure TForm2.CarregarImagemCanvas;
begin
  Canvas.Control := Panel1;
  BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height, Image.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;



procedure TForm2.btnPosicionarImagemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CarregarImagemBitmap;
  PosicionarPainel;
end;



procedure TForm2.btnCarregarImagemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CarregarImagemCanvas;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Victor, perdão pela demora... Nos testes que eu fiz o programa joga a imagem carregada pelo "LoadFromFile" para dentro do TBitmap, ficando apenas a imagem. Não permite que eu posicione a imagem dentro da área do canvas na posição que eu preciso... Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RodrigoTognin, dá uma olhada no exemplo que acabei de postar